# How to change title bar for a nsis application

Tags: nsis

I have made a simple app using nsis that renders web pages. Next requirement where I am stuck is to implementing a custom title bar, with custom controls. I imagined that I could do this with skins or via some existing plugin but was unable to find any viable solution for this.

Please suggest how I can change the title bar for a NSIS application.

Comment: Please reconsider using NSIS. You will find that bending it to your will in making an application becomes steadily more and more difficult. Use a tool designed for that (e.g. a language like Python with `win32gui`, PySide with QtWebkit or some other such toolkit). I know. I've produced NSIS-based GUIs, and they're a *lot* of work and the final result lacks flexibility, so that modifying it later is really hard. NSIS does installers well. It even does launchers fairly well (compare our usage of it for the PortableApps.com Launcher). But most GUI programs it does not do well.

Comment: We are in a way limited to using nsis only due to a client requirement. I agree that it might get difficult to continue development with nsis but most of the requirement is completed and we are only stuck with this one thing alone.

Comment: A client *requiring application development in NSIS*? Uh oh. Merely from the description (being blissfully unaware of any complicating or mitigating factors) I would have fired the client before now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in NSIS is to write a new plugin (There are no existing plugins that skin the non-client area because it is hard to do and usually looks like crap IMHO)

To do this you basically have to write 3 versions of the skin handling:

1. [<= Win2000](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-titlebar) and XP+ with uxtheme/visual styles off
2. XP/2003 with visual styles on
3. Vista+ with aero

...on top of that you might want to deal with high-contrast mode etc

NSIS never really comes into the picture other than calling your new plugin in .onguiinit to start hooking things, the rest needs to happen in the subclass handler and should probably be written in C/C++...